# Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: SQL=DELETE FROM `joom_session` WHERE `time` < '1408178025'

Tags: php, joomla3.2

I have taken file backup of website from Server. When I am using it on my local server, it is giving following errorr:

```
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: SQL=DELETE FROM `joom_session` WHERE `time` < '1408178025'
```

configuration file is looking perfect. I have search it on google but not found solution.
I trunked the session table also.

can anybody give me solution of it?

Answer (score 0):

this error is appear when your table corrupted.
you can repair your table and error gone.
login into your phpmyadmin , then click on your database name, then select your corrupted table, scroll down to bottom of page, in a dropdown box select repair.